# How can I prove that $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let we have the following functions  :

$f(x)=(\sin x)^4$ and $g(x)=(\cos x)^4$

How can I prove that $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mesurable for the Lebesgue measure?

Simple : they are continuous, and you can show that every continuous function is mesurable